# Ruby Ohm: do not raise unique index violation, just return false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ohm

In ohm when I try to save a unique attribute it raises an error if the attribute is not unique. Is there a way to have it simply return false instead of raising the error?

This is the type of code I want, but it raises an error if the domain is not unique, so it never reaches the `else` clause:

```
domain = Domain.new(:domain => root_domain)
if domain.save
    return domain
else
    return Domain.with(:domain => root_domain)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ruby rescue:

```
begin
  domain.save
  domain
rescue Ohm::UniqueIndexViolation
  return false
end
```